# Upload and retrieve files from Google Cloud Storage/ Buckets in Python/Django

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I want to upload and retrieve file (that includes image and csv) for my django application.

My project is currently hosted on Google App Engine Flexible. From my understanding, I need to use Google Cloud Buckets for the process. But I could not find relevant material online for the process.

[GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions#open) API also provides the feature of writing a file and reading it:

```
cloudstorage.open(filename, mode='r', content_type=None, options=None, read_buffer_size=storage_api.ReadBuffer.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE, retry_params=None)
```

Please point me to the relevant resources for the same. Since I am new to Django and Google Cloud, I would really appreciate if you could share code snippets with me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Check the [Google storage](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html) section of Django Storages. It may help to read generally about the storage system used in Django before going to Google storage in detail.

Answer (score 0):

As per the official documentation of Google App Engine Flexible, you can configure upload and retrieve files in different runtimes [environments](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-storage). I went through the documentation and I found that you need to create a Cloud Storage bucket in order to stock your files.Keep in mind that it's only for static content. I recommend to take a look at this documentation where you may find valuable information.

Please let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. However, after seeing the limitations of Google App Engine, I have moved on to using complete VPS server with django storage for handling static/media files